# Loop over named list of dfs, test condition on df's column, if true return name of list element

Tags: r, list, loops, lapply, named

I have a named list of data.frame objects (`training_data`). Each data.frame object will be tested based on a "x" column and if the test is passed, the name of that data.frame object is supposed to be returned.

In the case below, "a" and "b" are supposed to be returned:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10)
df1 <- data.frame(x=11:20, y=11:20)
training_data <- list(df, df, df1, df1)
names(training_data) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")

pos <- lapply(training_data, function(data) {
                                 if(data$x==1)
                                    ["return the name of the data.frame object in hand"]
                              })
```

My question is how exactly one can determine the name of the object currently being processed within any iteration of lapply and how to return that name so that it goes to "pos" list.

Regards

Comment: please `dput` some sample data.  if you don't understand, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  ..i've never seen `if` inside an `lapply` function, are you sure you don't want `ifelse` (which is vectorized)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use `lapply` here, you can access your list for example :

```
training_data[['pos']]
```

This will give you acess to the data.frame named 'pos' or posxx...

**EDIT** after OP clarification

I use lapply in the names of the list , I and I use the same mode of acces above to the main list

```
pos <- lapply(names(training_data), function(data) {
  if(training_data[[data]]$x==1)        ## here your condition is not correct
    data

})

  [[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]]
[1] "b"

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
NULL
```

You can remove the NULL elements using something like

```
unlist(pos)
[1] "a" "b"
```

but I think you will get better output here if you use `sapply`, which returns named list.

Comment: training_data is a list containing several data.frame objects. The condition is to be placed on label field contains inside the data.frame object.

Comment: No. You asked how to "determine the name of the object currently being processed"....Now the " label field contains inside the data.frame object" ? what do you mean ?the column name?

Comment: No. Not the column name. Each element (in this case dataframe object) of list is named. I want to determine the name of this data.frame is the following condition is true : if(x$label=="pos") then return the name of this data.frame object.

Comment: Or in other words, I want to determine all those data.frame objects where the label column contains a "pos" value.

Comment: @Shahzad I think you need really to give a reproducible example with the expected result.

Comment: I have edited the question now. Hope it will now make some sense. Thanks.

Comment: @Shahzad we want to help you, but you're not paying us - you have a responsibility to provide clearly-defined starting data and also your desired results.  [please read this carefully](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) :)

Comment: @AnthonyDamico. Its done sir. I have now edited the question. Thanks.